# Easy way to search a table used by stored procedure and views?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a few tables in SQL server 2008. I want to find a list of all the stored procedures and views that are using this table. I am new to SQL server, I think there has to be an easy way rather than opening each view and stored procedure and search for the table name. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id),
  OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [definition] LIKE '%table name%';
```

This is a little more reliable than the dependency views, because those rely on objects being compiled in the right order.

But there are some caveats:

---

This has the potential for false positives, of course, since you could have

```sql
-- table name
```

Or the table name you're searching for could be a common word that appears naturally in other code even though it doesn't reference that specific table.

---

This could potentially miss references, e.g. if you build strings dynamically or pass table names in to dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSMS, just right click on the table in the object explorer and choose "View Dependencies".

Comment: This is not all that reliable on its own, for various reasons. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: I tried this option earlier but I just got a message saying that discovery fails